# Почему PauseToken прерывает Task?

Tags: c#, wpf, асинхронность

Пытаюсь разобраться с PauseToken (Namespace: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace).

Не могу понять когда вызываю `PauseTokenSource.Pause();` PauseToken уходит в паузу и одновременно завершает task и я получаю сообщение "Completed".

Но при этом если после `PauseTokenSource.Pause();` вызвать `PauseTokenSource.Resume();`, то task продолжит работать, но по окончании никаких сообщений не будет.

Два вопроса почему так происходит, и как это можно поправить?

```
public PauseToken PauseToken;

private async Task DoDoneAsync()
{
    FlagCommandDone = true;

    try
    {
        task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                double i = 0;
                while (i < 3)
                {
                    i++;
                    await PauseToken.WaitWhilePausedAsync();
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
            }
        );
        await task;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        isError = true;
        message = e.Message;
    }

    if (!isError) message = task.IsCompleted ? "Completed" : "Canceled";

    MessageBox.Show(message);

    FlagCommandDone = false;
}
```

Comment: Вам уже ответили [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47958756/9024827)

Comment: @Bulson Ко мне приходят уведомления, но все равно спасибо. В данной ситуации и для моих целей полностью подходит исчерпывающий ответ VladD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема в `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Этот метод запускает обыкновенные функции как `Task`, но для асинхронных он делает не то, что вы ожидаете. Используйте `Task.Run` вместо него.

Давайте вспомним, как выполняются асинхронные функции. Ваш `async`-делегат с точки зрения внешнего кода не выполняется до конца, а завершается с первым внутренним `await`'ом, возвращая `Task` (который, в свою очередь, завершится с окончанием выполнения *всей* асинхронной функции). Следовательно, ваш `task` является не заданием выполнения *всей* асинхронной функции, а лишь заданием получения на неё `Task`'а! Действительно, сигнатура вашего `async`-делегата есть `Task f()`, а сигнатура функции, возвращённой из `Task.Factory.StartNew` — `Task<Task> f()`.

`Task.Run` обрабатывает эту ситуацию более ожидаемым образом: он получает `Task<Task>`, и делает внутри `await`, таким образом, вы дожидаетесь «внутреннего» таска, представляющего собой ваш асинхронный делегат.

---

Литература: [PFX team, Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) (кажется, русский перевод [тут](https://winexpert.uneta.ua/2014/09/16/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)).

Comment: Благодарю за полный ответ. За литературу отдельное спасибо. Буду изучать дальше.

Comment: @Kirill: Пожалуйста! Обязательно разберитесь с TPL и async/await, это на текущий момент самая лучшая фишка языка C#.